# Should a Form contain only one OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have a form with multiple buttons, each of them opens an `OpenFileDialog` and open a .txt file. Should I have one `OpenFileDialog` per button or only one for all of them? What is the common way of doing this? What are the pros and cons,

Comment: I can't imagine it makes a significant enough difference that this would be anything but opinion-based.  Have you encountered any actual problem with the code you've written?

Comment: @David Not a problem but an inconveniece. When I have two of them, and I have a method that uses them, I have to pass the `OpenFileDialog` so the method would know with which to work. However, having one per button seems more logic to me.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a code review.  There's a Code Review SE site which may be more appropriate.  Of course, showing the actual code will be necessary.

Comment: The `OpenFileDialog` is a `Component`  and as such allows you to set properties that you normally would have to set multiple times, **once** in the WinForm designer by allowing a single form to have **multiple** `OpenFileDialog`s each with different properties for such things as _file extensions; initial folder; filter_ and so on.  So _yes_ you could, though whether having multiple for _"txt"_ files is up to you

Comment: I'd even say that you *should* use multiple OpenFileDialog. The reason is, the different buttons provide different context to the user and this should be reflected by the OpenFileDialog instances. If a user changes current folder after pressing Button1 (e.g. to a folder with text files), he normally does not expect that folder to be mirrored to Button2 (e.g. for opening a folder with image files or text files in a different format).